# Node.json response

Tags: node.js, rest, stripe-payments, httpresponse

I am using stripe calls in node JS.

```
const balance = await stripe.balance.retrieve**********************;
```

These are the replies.
**first try **

console.log('successful', balance)

returns

successful {object: 'balance',
available: [ { amount: 5580, currency: 'aud', source_types: [Object] } ],
livemode: true,
pending: [ { amount: 0, currency: 'aud', source_types: [Object] } ]}

**second try**

console.log('successful',balance.amount);

returns
successful [ { amount: 5580, currency: 'aud', source_types: { card: 5580 } } ]

How do I access only the **amount** within the []?

I have tried multiple combinations

```
  const available = await balance.available;
 console.log('successful',balance.available);
 console.log('successful',balance.available[1]);
 console.log('successful',available.amount);
```

None have so far worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print as belove.

```
console.log('successful', balance[0].amount)
```

Comment: Nailed it ! dhruvin vaghasiya reply after change .. successful 5580. Thanks!